# How do I make passphrase prompts for ssh keys appear in the terminal, not as a graphical prompt?

Tags: macos, ssh, keychain

I'm SSHing into my mac and doing some stuff remotely through tmux (namely uploading some stuff to github). When I just tried to run a `git push`, my command kept stalling silently. I found ssh stalling on this message, `debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed`, and divined that the password prompt was being caught by the Keychain app and being displayed on the screen. I was able to get it to go through by using teamviewer to enter my password on-screen.

But how do I keep these private key prompts from going to the screen in the future? I'm fine with being prompted for my passphrase, but I would like it to happen in a terminal window in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the password for your key is managed by `ssh-agent` and it defaults to ask for your password using the GUI you mentioned. You could:

1. Unlock your key using the shell frontend to `ssh-agent` by calling `ssh-add`. In this case you might want to lock your key with `ssh-add -D` before you log out of the box.
2. Circumvent `ssh-agent` by temporarily unsetting the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable `ssh` uses to connect to the agent. You can do this for a single command like this

   ```
   SSH_AUTH_SOCK="" git push
   ```

   or for the whole shell session by calling `unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Marcel